# First day JDatePicker 1.3.4

Tags: java, swing

This my code

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300,300);
UtilDateModel model=new UtilDateModel();
Properties p=new Properties();
p.put("text.today","Today");
p.put("text.month","Month");
p.put("text.year","Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel=new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker=new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new 
DateLabelFormatter());
```

how can I set the first day of the week MONDAY, the `datePicker method.setFirstDayMonday()` I understand in version 1.3.4 does not work.

Comment: Did you also ask the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768739/first-day-of-the-week-jdatepicker-1-3-4)?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the datepicker with the firstDay option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  firstDay: 1
});
```

Get or set the firstDay option, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var firstDay = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "firstDay" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "firstDay", 1 );
```

Comment: we need the week to start on Monday

Comment: since you´re using a datePicker i think this could solve your answer, let me know what happens next.

Comment: How to do this in my program?

Comment: Change my code please