# First day of the week JDatePicker 1.3.4

Tags: java, swing

In my country, the week starts on Monday

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300, 300);
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
```

How do I change the code for the start of the week on Monday[image]

Comment: This code doesn't (directly) determine any date... You have to show us the code of `UtilDateModel`, most likely...

Comment: I need the week to start on Monday when I display it

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you with that... Safari is an Apple product and may use the US weeks (beginning on Sunday) by default. Google for possibilities of changing that.

Comment: Did you already ask the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756096/first-day-jdatepicker-1-3-4)?

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation for your date picker class